# Ingnore Custom validation for hidden fields in rails 2.3.5

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Is there any way to ignore custom validation in rails for hidden fields? For example there is any mandatory fields with `id='test'` and I try to hide this using:

```
$('test').hide();
```

After that I want to ignore validation.

Comment: Why? It sounds like you are trying to bypass some security features on a website that you do not control.

Comment: Actually i am working on an enhancement that is show text fields that are linked to particular category .there is a case some category has mandatory fields but are hidden for another category so i need to ignore the validation when mandatory fields are hidden

Comment: Firstly, I just answered your question with what I think is solid advice. Secondly, if you want different validations in different cases you could use different models for each case. `ModelName::AsMandatoryVariation` and `ModelName::AsNonMandatoryVariation`. An example would be: `User::AsRegisterable` and `User::AsAuthor`. In both models you'd have different validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue . I have bypass the validation by using attr_accessor
 Here  I set the value of category id and checked linked category id for the field is equal to category id

Answer (score 1):

Luckily you cannot tell Rails to ignore validation through javascript, your model controls what is valid and what isn't. Since your model lives on the server and not in your client there is no way you can change this through client-side code.

Judging from this question I think that it would be a good idea if you were to focus on learning the basics of web technology rather than diving into Rails and jQuery. You seem to miss a basic understanding of important concepts. To start with `jQuery('#something').hide()` does not make your input field hidden, it just hides the element from the user by giving it a hidden display style in CSS. Hidden form fields are a specific type of input field: `<input type='hidden' />`. They are usually used to embed meta-data in your forms.

So my advice to you is to start out with some online courses in HTML and Javascript and then starting with some beginner courses in Rails. The HTML and JS courses should not take you more than 1-2 week(s) if you put in some time and you will have a far better understanding of how the web works.